# How to set liquibase logging in Spring Boot 2.5.3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I have the newest spring boot in my project and liqubase whose version is provided by spring boot parent artifact.
I prefer default logback.
When I build it as jar its logging is working correctly.

```
INFO liquibase.logging.core.JavaLogger Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO liquibase.logging.core.JavaLogger Reading from public.databasechangelog
INFO liquibase.logging.core.JavaLogger Successfully released change log lock
INFO liquibase.logging.core.JavaLogger Successfully acquired change log lock
WARN liquibase.logging.core.JavaLogger Skipping auto-registration
INFO liquibase.logging.core.JavaLogger Successfully released change log lock
```

However if it’s built as war and deployed to Apache Tomcat 9.0.50, it doesn’t use logback and save logs to tomcat-stderr file.

```
INFO [main] liquibase.lockservice.null Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO [main] liquibase.changelog.null Reading from public.databasechangelog
INFO [main] liquibase.lockservice.null Successfully released change log lock
INFO [main] liquibase.lockservice.null Successfully acquired change log lock
WARNING [main] liquibase.hub.null Skipping auto-registration
```

I downgraded liqubase version to 3.10 and it’s working as war. What I noticed is that it’s using different class. Check it out.

```
INFO liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger Successfully acquired change log lock
```

Answer (score 0):

With Liquibase 4.0 we changed from our code using SLF4J logging to java.util.Logging by default.

But, there is an extension at https://github.com/mattbertolini/liquibase-slf4j which switches Liquibase back to using SLF4j for logging.